# Force to link against unused shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Moved from gcc 4.5 to gcc 4.6, and now it does not link against libraries that are not used at compile time (i.e. if no symbols are imported from them).

However the purpose of those libraries is that they execute static constructors and thus make themselves available to the app at runtime (register their symbols).

Is there a way to force gcc to link with all libraries listed via -l?

Comment: Probably a change in `as-needed` option. Try preceding your `-l` flags in `-Wl,-no-as-needed` (can't remember the exact syntax and can't access a compiler right now)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you need either `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to totally disable it. Or, `--no-as-needed -lfoo --as-needed` to disable "as-needed" just for `libfoo`.

Source: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/031991.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, now also trying with --copy-dt-needed-entries. Maybe need to recompile the sources files, not just relink?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and solved an annoying Undefined Symbols issue for me.